# How can I disable logging in console?

Tags: scala

```
[Stage 103:>                                                      (1 + 1) / 100]
[Stage 103:>              (2 + 1) / 100]
[Stage 105:>              (0 + 0) / 100]
[Stage 105:>                                                      (1 + 1) / 100]
[Stage 105:=>                                                     (2 + 1) / 100]
```

How can I disable the above logging in scala console?

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

It is still visible after using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running spark and want to disable some logging info. Go to the place you install your spark (for example: C:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\conf). And edit "log4j.properties" file. In "log4j.rootCategory=INFO, file, console" line, you should remove "console" to "log4j.rootCategory=INFO, file".